# C# Когда оправдан захват внешних переменных в анонимных методах?

Tags: c#, анонимная-функция

В C# предусмотрен механизм захвата внешних переменных в анонимных методах. Приведу пример кода:

```
private delegate void AddOp(int num);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = 0;

    AddOp add = delegate(int num)
    {
        result += num;
    };

    add(4);
    add(6);
    add(10);

    Console.WriteLine($"result = {result}");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Сам механизм захвата понятен, но я не могу найти ему реальное применение на практике. Можете привести примеры, когда это действительно оправдано?

Во многих руководствах пишут, что захват внешних переменных может порождать неявные ошибки, вызванные изменением этой переменной, поэтому у меня пока складывается такое мнение, что этот механизм лучше обходить стороной, например, так:

```
private delegate void AddOp2(ref int src, int num);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = 0;

    AddOp2 add = delegate(ref int src, int num)
    {
        src += num;
    };

    add(ref result, 4);
    add(ref result, 6);
    add(ref result, 10);

    Console.WriteLine($"result = {result}");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Для чего его придумали?

Comment: К примеру, можно встретить при обращении анонимного метода к UI или модели. Конкретно при использовании BackgroundWorker в WPF, ему можно передать анонимные функции в обработчики и обращаться свободно к данным класса. Или же передать анонимную функцию в обработчик таймера. Про ошибки - их может порождать все, что угодно, для вас это просто сигнал быть внимательнее и понимать, что делаете.

Comment: это применимо ко всему, где вы передаете функцию куда то. Например, `Task.Run(()=>{ захват })` или `myObject.OnClick+=(s, e)=>{ звхват }`. Часто делегат, что вы передаете, написан не вами, и вы не можете изменить его сигнатуру, что тогда? В общем, примеров полно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, ты создал анонимный метод и создал несколько Task'ов на его основе.

Так вот, в основном методе ты можешь объявить объект и использовать его внутри анонимного метода в качестве синхронизации:

```
var obj = new Object();
var task1 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
lock(obj){

}
})

var task2 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    lock (obj)
    {

    }
})
```

Так же в LINQ это повсеместно используется.

Например, тебе нужно отобрать значения, которые равны определенной переменной:

```
var a=10;
list.Where(x=>x==a);
```

В этом случае не нужно делать каких-либо лишних телодвижений, компилятор сам сделает.

Comment: Я немного неправильно поставил вопрос. Ваш пример понятен. Вот зачем компилятор дает возможность модифицировать внешнюю по отношению к анонимному методу переменную? Это ведь можно было бы запретить проверкой компилятора. Или все же в такой модификации иногда возникает необходимость?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko ну опять же пример с потоками: Можно в эту переменную писать какой-нибудь прогресс и в основном потоке читать и выводить прогресс на экран.

Comment: Ну вот например, в C# было запрещено объявлять переменную с одинаковым именем во внутреннем блоке, чтобы не порождать ошибки. В Си (возможно, и в C++, не помню точно) такое действо было разрешено

Comment: @AndreiKhotko ну да C# нельзя объявлять переменную внутри, которая объявлена снаружи. Что-то не представляю, как можно словить какую-то ошибку. По правилам хорошего тона замыкания могут использоваться в небольших функциях, а большие функции выносятся в отдельные методы.

Comment: Я просто хоть и давно изучаю .NET, но только сейчас начал изучать многопоточность, параллелизм и асинхронность. Возможно, я буду нести чушь, но все же задам вопрос. Просто я бы этот глобальный объект/переменную передавал в метод по ссылке. Почему вы именно глобально его передаете?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko если бы метод был бы большим, то я бы вынес его в отдельный класс, а если он небольшой и понятно, что там делается, то почему бы не намутить анонимный метод? Так-то обычно объекты блокировки прячут в приватных полях класса.

Comment: В целом, я все понял. Спасибо, что все пояснили :)